# Limits at infinity not neglecting added constants

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

This is such a simple question that I'm sure it must be answered somewhere, but I haven't had any luck finding an answer. I am trying to simplify expressions of the form:
$$f(x) = A\left(\frac{1+e^{x}}{e^{x}}\right)$$
I am interested in the case where $x \rightarrow \infty$, so $f(x) \rightarrow A$. However, taking the limit of f(x)/.Infinity in Mathematica returns an indeterminate expression. How do I force Mathematica to consider $1+e^{x} \rightarrow e^{x}$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I will post in mathematica code next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Limit[a (1 + Exp[x])/Exp[x], x -> \[Infinity]]
```

(* a *)

Works fine.

(Style note:  don't use upper-case letters to start the names of variables or constants or functions as it might conflict with *Mathematica*'s internal names.)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try this. I am embarrassed to say that I was evaluating at infinity rather than taking the limit to infinity.